# Test decorator parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-decorators

I have a decorator that accept two parameters `callback` and `onerror`, both should be callables something like this

```
class mydecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, callback, onerror=None):
        if callable(callback):
            self.callback = callback
        else:
            raise TypeError('Callable expected in "callback" parameter')

        self.onerror = onerror
        if self.onerror and not callable(self.onerror):
            raise TypeError('Callable expected in "onerror" parameter')

    def __call__(self, func):
        return self.__param__call__(func)

    def __param__call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                self.callback()
            except MyCustomException as e:
                if self.onerror:
                    self.onerror(e.message, e.data)
                else:
                    raise

            return result 
        return wrapper
```

I would like to test with I pass a invalid parameter, for example a non callable, it should raise a `TypeError`

Using Python `unittest` what is the best approach to achieve this? I'm willing to do something like:

```
def test_non_callable_callback_should_return_type_error(self):
    try:
        @mydecorator('this_is_not_a_callable')
        def my_phony_func():
            pass
    except TypeError:
        # Correctly has raised a TypeError, lets just pass
        pass
    else:
        # It has not raised an TypeError, let's fail
        self.fail('TypeError not raised when a non callable passed to callback')
```

It must be a better way, didn't?

Comment: There must be a better way to do what? Your use of a class with a callable instance is perfectly fine, if unusual (I am more accustomed to see regular functions being used as decorators). The test is OK, too. If you use py.test, it has a convenient  `with pytest.raises(SystemExit): ...code...` that makes such tests a bit more compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Leo K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9962955/leo-k) commented, there's a much easier way to test if some code raises an exception in a test, though different libraries spell things slightly differently. In a `unittest.TestCase`, you can use `self.assertRaises` as a context manager:

```
def test_non_callable_callback_should_return_type_error(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        @mydecorator('this_is_not_a_callable')
        def my_phony_func():
            pass
```

In fact, you could simplify things even more by doing away with unnecessary parts of the code being tested. Since you expect the `mydecorator` class to raise the exception when it is called (rather than when the instance is called on the function), you can get rid of the dummy function and skip the `@decorator` syntax all together. The `assertRaises` method can even make the call for you:

```
def test_non_callable_callback_should_return_type_error(self):
    self.assertraises(TypeError, mydecorator, 'this_is_not_a_callable')
```